# GLib program termination signal handling?

Tags: c, signals, glib

I've recently been exposed to GLib and am playing around with it.  I have been able to replace a good deal of my C library functions with GLib functions (as an aside, I'm a huge fan of the command line handling!).  However, one thing I haven't been able to find much documentation on is signal handling from the OS.  Namely in Linux, is there a better way that I can handle CTRL+C or other signals to terminate the application?  Currently I use signal(), but I'm wondering if there's a way that I can set up my handler for CTRL+C through GLib.

As always, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a way of using signals via [GLIB](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/)! These are some of functions available for handling signals:

```
guint               g_unix_signal_add                   (gint signum,
                                                         GSourceFunc handler,
                                                         gpointer user_data);
guint               g_unix_signal_add_full              (gint priority,
                                                         gint signum,
                                                         GSourceFunc handler,
                                                         gpointer user_data,
                                                         GDestroyNotify notify);
GSource *           g_unix_signal_source_new            (gint signum);
```

Check out *[UNIX-specific utilities and integration, , g_unix_signal_add()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-UNIX-specific-utilities-and-integration.html#g-unix-signal-add)*.

Comment: So I can just replace signal() with g_unix_signal_add()?  That seems deceptively easy...

Comment: Why should it be more difficult? g_unix_signal_add is definied as a convenience function for g_unix_signal_source_new(), which attaches to the default GMainContex. You can achieve the same result using also this function g_unix_signal_source_new ().

Comment: What is the platform independent way to solve this?